# Run Gate pipeline in eclipse I get this error Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gate.resource

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu, gate

I want to create Web service in eclipse + Tomcate v7 and use pipeline I created in Gate in Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

but I get this error: 
can you help me for solving this error??

```
INFO: Exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gate/Resource
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.cache.ClassCache.lookup(ClassCache.java:85)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceClass(JavaProvider.java:428)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.initServiceDesc(JavaProvider.java:461)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.getInitializedServiceDesc(SOAPService.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.makeNewInstance(WSDDService.java:500)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getService(WSDDDeployment.java:427)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gate.Resource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Try doing a self help here and let me know if you still face issue http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Add all jar files in following folders in your build path:

```
.../GATE_Developer_7.1/bin/
.../GATE_Developer_7.1/lib/
```

Comment: I add all jars in this two folders but the error appear again :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is a bit late, but I had the same error and found that it's due to the use of '~' for $HOME.

Changing ~/Gate/bin/gate.jar with /home/user/Gate/bin/gate.jar solved the problem for me.